# Query performance - 'Left join is null' vs 'Not exists select'

Tags: mariadb

I have a question about a query that I want to execute, but I dont know what is the best qua performance. I need to get all the words exclude the words that have a relation with the table wordfilter.

The output of the queries is right, but maybe there is a better solution for this. I have almost none knowledge about query plans, I'm trying to understand it now.

```
SELECT CONCAT(SPACE(1), UCASE(stocknews.word.word), SPACE(1)) AS word, stocknews.word.language 
FROM stocknews.word 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT word_id FROM stocknews.wordfilter WHERE stocknews.word.id = word_id) 
AND user_id = 1

+----+--------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type  | table      | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | extra       |
+----+--------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | word       | ref   | user_id       | user_id | 4       | const | 843  | Using where |
|  2 | MATERIALIZED | wordfilter | index | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 756     |       | 16   | Using index |
+----+--------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+
```

Against

```
SELECT CONCAT(SPACE(1), UCASE(stocknews.word.word), SPACE(1)) AS word, stocknews.word.language 
FROM stocknews.word 
LEFT JOIN stocknews.wordfilter ON stocknews.word.id = stocknews.wordfilter.word_id 
WHERE stocknews.wordfilter.word_id IS NULL AND user_id = 1

+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+---------+------+--------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref     | rows | extra                                |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+---------+------+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | word       | ref  | user_id       | user_id | 4       | const   | 843  |                                      |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wordfilter | ref  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | word.id | 1    | Using where; Using index; Not exists |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+---------+------+--------------------------------------+
```

Any help is welcome! An explanation would be nice.

**Edit:**

For query 1:

```
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| Handler_commit             | 1     |
| Handler_delete             | 0     |
| Handler_discover           | 0     |
| Handler_external_lock      | 0     |
| Handler_icp_attempts       | 0     |
| Handler_icp_match          | 0     |
| Handler_mrr_init           | 0     |
| Handler_mrr_key_refills    | 0     |
| Handler_mrr_rowid_refills  | 0     |
| Handler_prepare            | 0     |
| Handler_read_first         | 1     |
| Handler_read_key           | 1044  |
| Handler_read_last          | 0     |
| Handler_read_next          | 859   |
| Handler_read_prev          | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd           | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd_deleted   | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd_next      | 0     |
| Handler_rollback           | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint          | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback | 0     |
| Handler_tmp_update         | 0     |
| Handler_tmp_write          | 215   |
| Handler_update             | 0     |
| Handler_write              | 0     |
+----------------------------+-------+
25 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

For query 2:

```
+----------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name              | Value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| Handler_commit             | 1     |
| Handler_delete             | 0     |
| Handler_discover           | 0     |
| Handler_external_lock      | 0     |
| Handler_icp_attempts       | 0     |
| Handler_icp_match          | 0     |
| Handler_mrr_init           | 0     |
| Handler_mrr_key_refills    | 0     |
| Handler_mrr_rowid_refills  | 0     |
| Handler_prepare            | 0     |
| Handler_read_first         | 0     |
| Handler_read_key           | 844   |
| Handler_read_last          | 0     |
| Handler_read_next          | 843   |
| Handler_read_prev          | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd           | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd_deleted   | 0     |
| Handler_read_rnd_next      | 0     |
| Handler_rollback           | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint          | 0     |
| Handler_savepoint_rollback | 0     |
| Handler_tmp_update         | 0     |
| Handler_tmp_write          | 0     |
| Handler_update             | 0     |
| Handler_write              | 0     |
+----------------------------+-------+
```

Comment: Have you tried both and compared the performance? Generally speaking (at least in SQL Server, not sure about MariaDB), if your tables are indexed properly, `EXISTS` and `NOT EXISTS` perform faster because they are short circuit operators. As soon as a record is found, it is excluded or included, based on your query. `LEFT JOIN` includes all records regardless and filters them at the end with your `IS NULL` criteria.

Comment: I tried both of them on a small dataset and both had the same result. Thanks for the information, I'm almost sure that my indexes are set propely. I guess I need to make a bigger dataset to see any difference. My main question was also to hear what the query made it faster or slower. So I guess the `NOT EXISTS` method is faster. I will test it with a bigger dataset and report what query was actual faster. Thanks

Comment: It seems that the `NOT EXISTS` method is faster when there are 13.000 records in _word_ and 5000 records in _wordfilter_

Comment: @PatrickTucci - notice how the `LEFT JOIN` is optimized into "Not exists".  So it does not actually include "all records regardless".

Comment: @ThomasBoersma - Do `FLUSH STATUS; SELECT ... ; SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';` for each query.  That will give some low level numbers that somewhat map to performance.

Comment: @RickJames I edited the question with the query you provided. I'm not a sql expert, so some explanation would be nice about the data I get or a link with some information about the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a close race between the two formulations.  (Some other example may show a clearer winner.)

From the HANDLER values: Query 1 did more read_keys, and some writing (which goes along with MATERIALIZED). The other numbers were about same. So, I conclude that Query 1 is slower -- although possibly not enough slower to make much difference.

I vote for LEFT JOIN as the better query pattern (in this case)